# How to make the slave nodes work for Spark cluster using EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr

I tried to run a job on my Spark cluster using EMR. The cluster has one master and two slaves, and each node (master or slave node) has 32 cores. The job was using "Add Step" through the console, the configuration is set below:

sparkConf.setMaster("local[24]").set("spark.executor.memory", "40g")
            .set("spark.driver.memory", "40g");

Then I noticed that the two slaves didn't work (CPU usage close to 0), only master was working hard. How do I fix this problem and make the slaves work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a 'local' master that means the master is local - it is not distributed over the nodes.

You should follow the doc: 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html

Comment: Hi, do I need to set sparkConf.setMaster("yarn-cluster") ? Or don't set anything and ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster will take care of it? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use sparkConf.setMaster. Use --master yarn-cluster argument

Answer (score 1):

I've only recently started working with Spark on EMR, but I've found [these examples](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/examples/spark-submit-via-step.md) extremely helpful for launching / configuring the cluster and submitting Spark jobs.

Comment: Hi, do you need to do any configuration on the EMR cluster like http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html ? Thanks!

Comment: The EMR bootstrap for Spark (https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/blob/master/spark/README.md) sets up everything you need for running Spark on YARN.  Don't use the standalone mode within EMR.  Just set --master to yarn-client or yarn-cluster depending on your need.